# IBM Domino: View formula with @now

Tags: lotus-domino

There are some views which has columns with formula including @now. These columns are used to calculate days from now. But these views are so slow. I just need to get documents in specific category from result of view. Are there any setting in view to get category's document before calculate days? Or do I have to remove days columns from view and write an agent to add&calculate days columns to the view's result?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with IBM Domino, so if there is something wrong in my question, tell me please. I google the solution but can't find the result so I have to ask this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Or [do] I have to remove days columns from view and write an agent to add&calculate days columns to the view's result?"

Yes.  @Now in a view formula is a recipe for poor performance.  Create a scheduled agent that runs once per day and updates a field on the document then show that field in the view.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I found there is a form named "$$ViewTemplateDefault" used to process view data. Is this place the correct place to calculate days?

Comment: $$ViewTemplateDefault is a form used to display views on the Web and has nothing to do with calculating days.  You need to create an agent that is scheduled to run once per day, selects the documents you want to update and then for each, calculate the # of days and write that value to a field on the document.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to add some logic in $$ViewTemplateDefault to calculate days for each cells in the time column and update value in html. Seems like it is not a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

This column formula allows you to add a Today value without using @Today and hence lots of continual processing;

```
TodayDateString:= "Today";
Today := @TextToTime(TodayDateString);
@Abs(@Integer((Today - DateToCompare) / (60 * 60 * 24)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: As @JSmart523 said, there is an risk that index will out of date.

Answer (score 1):

Already answered, but I still felt the need to add my thoughts.

If you can afford to touch your documents every day (e.g. it's just a web on a single or clustered server) then I'd seriously consider writing an agent that updates a "NumDaysOld" field.

The reason why performance is slow if you have @Now or @Today in a view selection or column formula is because the indexer then knows that it is time-dependent and therefore doesn't store the view index (or maybe just doesn't store the entire index, I'm not sure), causing it to rebuild every time it's accessed.

If you cheat this by using @TextToTime("Today") then your view indexes risk being out of date because if a document doesn't change for n days, the view doesn't change for n days, and the indexer isn't triggered...

Perhaps a best practice would be to write an agent to change the column formula every day so that instead of @Today, use a literal date (by using square brackets, like [5/29/2018]) and then write an agent to change that column formula every day. I've never tried that because that wasn't available to me when I had needed to do something like this. (It's been a long time.) Instead I have resolved this need by:

- writing an agent that modified each document to update the age of the document, or
- making folders for "< 1 month", "2 to 6 months", etc., and had a daily agent that would populating/correct the folders, or
- avoiding the problem by having a view of open documents sorted by date and then trying to convince the end-users that was close enough! :-P (not proud of this one)

Comment: Thanks a lot, as you said, @TextToTime("Today") doesn't worked as expected, index is out of date.

Comment: I stand corrected. I have used this for years without problem, however, the views where I have used it have been very active so I haven't noticed an issue.